# What's the performance impact of calling an empty Action?

Tags: c#

Suppose that we have a class like this :

```
public class Task
{
      public Action PostAction=()=>{}

      public void Do()
      {
             //Do Some Stuffs
             PostAction();
      }
}
```

As you can see PostAction is there so we can inject a post action.

Now suppose we have a list of Tasks that some of them has a post action and most of them don't and we are calling them like this :

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
      task.Do();
```

Do empty post actions have any performance impact on execution of the above code ?

Comment: You could have trace that faster than writing that question :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes up pretty often because your code is also a hack around having to do the null test when you raise an event.  The jitter optimizer cannot do anything to optimize the do-nothing call away, it cannot see beyond the delegate invocation.  The fast version of this code avoids making the delegate call:

```
public class Task {
      public Action PostAction;

      public void Do() {
          if (PostAction != null) PostAction();
      }
}
```

Profiling the difference with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch is very tricky, delegates invocations are quite fast.  I ensured that the Do() call could not be inlined by giving it the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Noinlining)] attribute.  Average measurements on my not-very-fast laptop with a mobile Haswell chip:

- Empty Do(): 3.9 nanoseconds/call
- Null test : 4.3 nanoseconds/call = 4.3 - 3.9 ~= 0.4 nsec
- Invoke : 7.5 nanoseconds/call = 7.5 - 3.9 ~= 3.6 nsec

Beware that the "Empty Do()" measurement includes the overhead of performing the test, a for(;;) loop as well as making the method call.  That is constant overhead in all the measurements.

You can tell the cost, the delegate call is (3.6 - 0.4) / 0.4 ~= 800% slower than the null test.  You can get the number friendlier if you assume the constant overhead is representative (it isn't): (7.5 - 4.3) / 4.3 ~= 75% slower.  Your foreach loop will have more overhead, thus lowering the perf loss percentage.  A test iterating with a Enumerable.Range with foreach produced (17.0 - 13.9) / 13.9 ~= 22% slower.

These are fairly substantial numbers of course.  However, the *absolute* number is very low.  If you don't call the delegate very often, or there is a lot of `//Do Some Stuffs` (thus raising the constant overhead), then the perf loss can get hard to notice.

Testing for null, as shown in any example code that demonstrates how to raise events, is the recommended way.  You only have a good reason to use the lambda if you have a very high expectation that the delegate is going to be replaced (i.e. the event is going to be subscribed).  In which case you optimized the null check away, saving about a single CPU cycle per call.

Comment: my guideline is first having a profiled bottleneck before searching to optimize away this kind of thing but it could be interesting to add another test case at this. Using the new C#6 feature, the [null-conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) operator : `public void Do() { PostAction?.Invoke (); }`